# PHP check function parameters without calling it

Tags: php, function, parameters, xml-rpc

I am creating a xml-rpc server and now i got to a phase where i want to check if the parameters sent to me in request could be applied to the method specified in . I could hard code it for every method i call, but would be no fun, so i decided to take it more dynamically. To be specific, i need to count parameters and determine their types without actually passing them to the callback method. The closest i could find was "func-get-args" which is nowhere near to what i need to achieve.

User (Developer using my class) has to pass an array of methods, that xml-rpc request can call, so my original idea was to just force user to fill info about parameters into this array, but then i realised, how much would i hate myself for this every time i would do some changes. So i consider this a dead-end.

Can you help me out or at least point a direction?

Comment: This isn't how you should handle API calls. You could implement a 2 parameter system, where the first one is the method as described in your own documentation and the second one is the array with the parameters. That could potentially work but is an error-prone solution

Comment: Check out Reflection mechanism. It could help you with your idea

Comment: @FMashiro I am trying to provide some general solution, that dynamically filters out bad requests before they are passed to the developers code. Every developer should include his own security solutions, this is not to be considered full security solution. It should be more like a basic spam filter.
What you are saying is implemented already by following xml-rpc specs, but you evidently fail to see the problem. I need a way to "scan" the method that should be called, not the request.